# Design editor can not show anything in android studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.3

After updating 'Android studio' to version 3.4 , design editor can't display UI and displays this message as you can see in image below.

**Design editor is unavailable until a successful build**

What can I do to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: What about cache invalidating and restarting, clean and rebuild, and other typical solutions for android studio? Have you updated gradle plugin version?

Comment: @Ufkoku Thanks for your response, but not worked for me.

Comment: have you any errors in your gradle console? Or is there "build successful" message?

Comment: @Ufkoku you see the message in the editor, right? That means the Gradle build failed. OP didn't check to see if it succeeded or not, but the warning there states the build failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, updating `buildToolsVersion` to latest version fixed my problem.

P.S: cache invalidating and restarting, clean and rebuild, and other typical solutions for android studio not worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your Gradle build failed, so Android Studio blocks access to the editor until the build is successful. No I don't know why it works like that, it just does.

So rebuild your project by going to the Build tab (in the bar at the top where you see "File", "View", etc) and press "Make project". Fix any errors from the build and you can use it again.

Alternatively, if the build did succeed but still shows like that, invalidate the caches and restart. Clean and rebuild is also a good option, though your problem will most likely be solved by building the project.

Comment: Did you actually try all of it? Cleaning and rebuilding, building the project and invalidating caches and restarting? Because every time this has happened to me, that solved it. This isn't an AS 3 bug, this is your Gradle build failing. Check the Gradle console too